# Watchman: C compiler cannot create executables

Tags: compiling, c

I try to install Watchman for React Native.

At the configure I get the following error:

> configure: error: in '/home/maxim/watchman':
> configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
> See 'config.log' for more details

config.log:

```
This file contains any messages produced by compilers while
running configure, to aid debugging if configure makes a mistake.

It was created by watchman configure 4.9.0, which was
generated by GNU Autoconf 2.69.  Invocation command line was

  $ ./configure 

## --------- ##
## Platform. ##
## --------- ##

hostname = maxim-MS-7817
uname -m = x86_64
uname -r = 5.8.0-59-generic
uname -s = Linux
uname -v = #66~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jun 17 11:14:10 UTC 2021

/usr/bin/uname -p = x86_64
/bin/uname -X     = unknown

/bin/arch              = x86_64
/usr/bin/arch -k       = unknown
/usr/convex/getsysinfo = unknown
/usr/bin/hostinfo      = unknown
/bin/machine           = unknown
/usr/bin/oslevel       = unknown
/bin/universe          = unknown

PATH: /usr/local/sbin
PATH: /usr/local/bin
PATH: /usr/sbin
PATH: /usr/bin
PATH: /sbin
PATH: /bin
PATH: /usr/games
PATH: /usr/local/games
PATH: /snap/bin
PATH: /home/maxim/Android/Sdk/emulator
PATH: /home/maxim/Android/Sdk/tools
PATH: /home/maxim/Android/Sdk/tools/bin
PATH: /home/maxim/Android/Sdk/platform-tools


## ----------- ##
## Core tests. ##
## ----------- ##

configure:2564: checking build system type
configure:2578: result: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
configure:2598: checking host system type
configure:2611: result: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
configure:2631: checking target system type
configure:2644: result: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
configure:2686: checking for a BSD-compatible install
configure:2754: result: /usr/local/bin/install -c
configure:2765: checking whether build environment is sane
configure:2820: result: yes
configure:2969: checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p
configure:3008: result: /usr/local/bin/mkdir -p
configure:3015: checking for gawk
configure:3045: result: no
configure:3015: checking for mawk
configure:3031: found /usr/local/bin/mawk
configure:3042: result: mawk
configure:3053: checking whether make sets $(MAKE)
configure:3075: result: yes
configure:3104: checking whether make supports nested variables
configure:3121: result: yes
configure:3258: checking whether make supports nested variables
configure:3275: result: yes
configure:3346: checking for gcc
configure:3362: found /usr/local/bin/gcc
configure:3373: result: gcc
configure:3602: checking for C compiler version
configure:3611: gcc --version >&5
gcc (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 9.3.0
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

configure:3622: $? = 0
configure:3611: gcc -v >&5
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
OFFLOAD_TARGET_NAMES=nvptx-none:hsa
OFFLOAD_TARGET_DEFAULT=1
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-9/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,go,brig,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++,gm2 --prefix=/usr --with-gcc-major-version-only --program-suffix=-9 --program-prefix=x86_64-linux-gnu- --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-vtable-verify --enable-plugin --enable-default-pie --with-system-zlib --with-target-system-zlib=auto --enable-objc-gc=auto --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --enable-multilib --with-tune=generic --enable-offload-targets=nvptx-none=/build/gcc-9-HskZEa/gcc-9-9.3.0/debian/tmp-nvptx/usr,hsa --without-cuda-driver --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 9.3.0 (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 
configure:3622: $? = 0
configure:3611: gcc -V >&5
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-V'
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
configure:3622: $? = 1
configure:3611: gcc -qversion >&5
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-qversion'; did you mean '--version'?
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
configure:3622: $? = 1
configure:3642: checking whether the C compiler works
configure:3664: gcc   -D_REENTRANT -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE  conftest.c  >&5
gcc: fatal error: cannot execute 'cc1': execvp: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
configure:3668: $? = 1
configure:3706: result: no
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME "watchman"
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME "watchman"
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION "4.9.0"
| #define PACKAGE_STRING "watchman 4.9.0"
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
| #define PACKAGE_URL ""
| #define PACKAGE "watchman"
| #define VERSION "4.9.0"
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| 
| int
| main ()
| {
| 
|   ;
|   return 0;
| }
configure:3711: error: in `/home/maxim/watchman':
configure:3713: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details

## ---------------- ##
## Cache variables. ##
## ---------------- ##

ac_cv_build=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
ac_cv_env_CCASFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CCASFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CCAS_set=
ac_cv_env_CCAS_value=
ac_cv_env_CCC_set=
ac_cv_env_CCC_value=
ac_cv_env_CC_set=
ac_cv_env_CC_value=
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CPP_set=
ac_cv_env_CPP_value=
ac_cv_env_CXXCPP_set=
ac_cv_env_CXXCPP_value=
ac_cv_env_CXXFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CXXFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CXX_set=
ac_cv_env_CXX_value=
ac_cv_env_FOLLY_CFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_FOLLY_CFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_FOLLY_LIBS_set=
ac_cv_env_FOLLY_LIBS_value=
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_LIBS_set=
ac_cv_env_LIBS_value=
ac_cv_env_LT_SYS_LIBRARY_PATH_set=
ac_cv_env_LT_SYS_LIBRARY_PATH_value=
ac_cv_env_PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR_set=
ac_cv_env_PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR_value=
ac_cv_env_PKG_CONFIG_PATH_set=
ac_cv_env_PKG_CONFIG_PATH_value=
ac_cv_env_PKG_CONFIG_set=
ac_cv_env_PKG_CONFIG_value=
ac_cv_env_PYTHON_set=
ac_cv_env_PYTHON_value=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_value=
ac_cv_host=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
ac_cv_path_install='/usr/local/bin/install -c'
ac_cv_path_mkdir=/usr/local/bin/mkdir
ac_cv_prog_AWK=mawk
ac_cv_prog_ac_ct_CC=gcc
ac_cv_prog_make_make_set=yes
ac_cv_target=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
am_cv_make_support_nested_variables=yes

## ----------------- ##
## Output variables. ##
## ----------------- ##

ACLOCAL='${SHELL} /home/maxim/watchman/missing aclocal-1.16'
AMDEPBACKSLASH=''
AMDEP_FALSE=''
AMDEP_TRUE=''
AMTAR='$${TAR-tar}'
AM_BACKSLASH='\'
AM_DEFAULT_V='$(AM_DEFAULT_VERBOSITY)'
AM_DEFAULT_VERBOSITY='0'
AM_V='$(V)'
AR=''
ARCHFLAGS=''
AUTOCONF='${SHELL} /home/maxim/watchman/missing autoconf'
AUTOHEADER='${SHELL} /home/maxim/watchman/missing autoheader'
AUTOMAKE='${SHELL} /home/maxim/watchman/missing automake-1.16'
AWK='mawk'
CC='gcc'
CCAS=''
CCASDEPMODE=''
CCASFLAGS=''
CCDEPMODE=''
CFLAGS=''
CPP=''
CPPFLAGS=' -D_REENTRANT -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE'
CXX=''
CXXCPP=''
CXXDEPMODE=''
CXXFLAGS=''
CYGPATH_W='echo'
DEFS=''
DEPDIR=''
DEV_FSEVENTS_FALSE=''
DEV_FSEVENTS_TRUE=''
DLLTOOL=''
DSYMUTIL=''
DUMPBIN=''
ECHO_C=''
ECHO_N='-n'
ECHO_T=''
EGREP=''
ENABLE_CPPCLIENT_FALSE=''
ENABLE_CPPCLIENT_TRUE=''
EXEEXT=''
FGREP=''
FOLLY_CFLAGS=''
FOLLY_LIBS=''
GREP=''
HAVE_CXX11=''
HAVE_PYTHON_FALSE=''
HAVE_PYTHON_TRUE=''
HAVE_RUBY_FALSE=''
HAVE_RUBY_TRUE=''
INSTALL_DATA='${INSTALL} -m 644'
INSTALL_PROGRAM='${INSTALL}'
INSTALL_SCRIPT='${INSTALL}'
INSTALL_STRIP_PROGRAM='$(install_sh) -c -s'
IRONMANCFLAGS=''
LD=''
LDFLAGS=''
LIBOBJS=''
LIBS=''
LIBTOOL=''
LIPO=''
LN_S=''
LTLIBOBJS=''
LT_SYS_LIBRARY_PATH=''
MAKEINFO='${SHELL} /home/maxim/watchman/missing makeinfo'
MANIFEST_TOOL=''
MKDIR_P='/usr/local/bin/mkdir -p'
NM=''
NMEDIT=''
OBJDUMP=''
OBJEXT=''
OTOOL64=''
OTOOL=''
PACKAGE='watchman'
PACKAGE_BUGREPORT=''
PACKAGE_NAME='watchman'
PACKAGE_STRING='watchman 4.9.0'
PACKAGE_TARNAME='watchman'
PACKAGE_URL=''
PACKAGE_VERSION='4.9.0'
PATH_SEPARATOR=':'
PCRE_CONFIG_PATH=''
PKG_CONFIG=''
PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR=''
PKG_CONFIG_PATH=''
PYTHON=''
PYTHON_EXEC_PREFIX=''
PYTHON_PLATFORM=''
PYTHON_PREFIX=''
PYTHON_VERSION=''
RANLIB=''
SED=''
SET_MAKE=''
SHELL='/bin/bash'
STRIP=''
VERSION='4.9.0'
WATCHMAN_STATE_DIR=''
WATCHMAN_STATE_DIR_FALSE=''
WATCHMAN_STATE_DIR_TRUE=''
ac_ct_AR=''
ac_ct_CC='gcc'
ac_ct_CXX=''
ac_ct_DUMPBIN=''
am__EXEEXT_FALSE=''
am__EXEEXT_TRUE=''
am__fastdepCCAS_FALSE=''
am__fastdepCCAS_TRUE=''
am__fastdepCC_FALSE=''
am__fastdepCC_TRUE=''
am__fastdepCXX_FALSE=''
am__fastdepCXX_TRUE=''
am__include=''
am__isrc=''
am__leading_dot='.'
am__nodep=''
am__quote=''
am__tar='$${TAR-tar} chof - "$$tardir"'
am__untar='$${TAR-tar} xf -'
bindir='${exec_prefix}/bin'
build='x86_64-pc-linux-gnu'
build_alias=''
build_cpu='x86_64'
build_os='linux-gnu'
build_vendor='pc'
datadir='${datarootdir}'
datarootdir='${prefix}/share'
docdir='${datarootdir}/doc/${PACKAGE_TARNAME}'
dvidir='${docdir}'
exec_prefix='NONE'
host='x86_64-pc-linux-gnu'
host_alias=''
host_cpu='x86_64'
host_os='linux-gnu'
host_vendor='pc'
htmldir='${docdir}'
includedir='${prefix}/include'
infodir='${datarootdir}/info'
install_sh='${SHELL} /home/maxim/watchman/install-sh'
libdir='${exec_prefix}/lib'
libexecdir='${exec_prefix}/libexec'
localedir='${datarootdir}/locale'
localstatedir='${prefix}/var'
mandir='${datarootdir}/man'
mkdir_p='$(MKDIR_P)'
oldincludedir='/usr/include'
pdfdir='${docdir}'
pkgpyexecdir=''
pkgpythondir=''
prefix='NONE'
program_transform_name='s,x,x,'
psdir='${docdir}'
pyexecdir=''
pythondir=''
runstatedir='${localstatedir}/run'
sbindir='${exec_prefix}/sbin'
sharedstatedir='${prefix}/com'
sysconfdir='${prefix}/etc'
target='x86_64-pc-linux-gnu'
target_alias=''
target_cpu='x86_64'
target_os='linux-gnu'
target_vendor='pc'

## ----------- ##
## confdefs.h. ##
## ----------- ##

/* confdefs.h */
#define PACKAGE_NAME "watchman"
#define PACKAGE_TARNAME "watchman"
#define PACKAGE_VERSION "4.9.0"
#define PACKAGE_STRING "watchman 4.9.0"
#define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
#define PACKAGE_URL ""
#define PACKAGE "watchman"
#define VERSION "4.9.0"

configure: exit 77
```

I already tried and have downloaded:

> version 4.7.0 of watchman repo
> to update and upgrade my system
> reinstall everything(watchman repo, autogen.sh) twice
>
> $ sudo apt install libc6-dev
> sudo apt-get install build-essential
> $ sudo apt-get install -y autoconf automake build-essential python-dev libtool libssl-dev\

Comment: The configure script seems to be finding binaries in /usr/local/bin i.e. `/usr/local/bin/gcc` and `/usr/local/bin/mkdir -p` etc. That is unusual - the version of `gcc` installed as as a dependency of the build-essential package would normally go in `/usr/bin` for example

Comment: What was wrong with https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/watchman ?